# Meaning of imaginary part of $\int_0^6 e^{x^3} dx$

Tags: integration, exponentiation

[image]

My question is the title itself.
How can it be possible that integral of real numbers can have an imaginary part?

Comment: Note that the imaginary part is very small compared to the real one.

Comment: It doesn't say it's equal to that, it says it's approximately equal to that...

Comment: It is just a numerical issue. The integral of a real integrable function is obviously a real number.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what numerical technique will give answers like this?

Comment: A little experimentation shows WA gives a real answer if you replace the upper limit $6$ with $1$ or $2$, but for $3$ gives $-E_{(2/3)}(-27)-(-1)^{(2/3)} \Gamma(4/3)\approx2.02255×10^{10}+1.09784×10^{-6} i$.

Comment: Replacing "from x=0 to 6" with "from x=0. to 6." appears to remove the imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in [0,6]$, then $x$ is real, so $x^3$ is real, so $e^{x^3}$ is (positive) real. So: $$\int_0^6 e^{x^3}dx \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}.$$

So the way I see it, there's basically two possibilities.

1. Wolfram alpha is just wrong. This is entirely possible, since its not based on a rigorous formalization of mathematics, more like a haphazard mess of ideas that seem to work most of the time.
2. Alternatively, perhaps the problem is that the symbol $\approx$ is fundamentally meaningless. What's meaningful is $a \approx b : r$, which can be defined to mean $d(a,b) \leq r$ in any metric space. Btw, this is basically how you get a [uniform structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) from a metric. Anyway, the point is that mathematical software that fails to compute a rigorous upper bound on its error terms is fundamentally pretty useless.

In motto form: "The Error term is God."